# Trouble assigning responseText from jQuery ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have been working on a simple test giver app. Everything has worked fine with the JSON allQuestions object embedded in code. Now I want to move the allQuestions object out of the index file and into `test.json` and retrieve it via jQuery AJAX call.

I assume I need to keep allQuestions as a global variable, because I manipulate it in other places in the script.

I get an "allQuestions is null error" first time it is encountered in script.

Tried declaring it as an array and I got an *allQuestions undefined* exception. Here is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/alank90/geoevhke/33/) version with JSON embedded (sorry I haven't figured out yet how to use AJAX functiaonality in jsfiddle yet). When I comment out the json and substitute :

```
var allQuestions = null;
    // jQuery AJAX request to read JSON formatted Test Questions & Answers from file
     $.ajax({
        url: "test.json",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(result) {
           allQuestions = result;
        }
      });
```

I see via firebug I get response ok:

```
[{
    question: ["Who is Prime Minister of the United Kingdom?", "Who is the Vice-President of the United
 States?", "Who is Chancellor of Germany?", "Who is the Prime Minister of Canada?"],
    choices: [
      ["David Cameron", "Gordon Brown", "Winston Churchill", "Tony Blair"],
      ["Barack Obama", "Bernie Sanders", "Nancy Pelosi", "Joe Biden"],
      ["Franz Ritz", "Angela Merkel", "Jan Schroeder", "John Stevens", "Karl Marx"],
      ["Wayne Gretsky", "Pierre Trudeau", "Mike Myers", "Justin Trudeau", "Justin Bieber"]
    ],
    correctAnswer: [0, 3, 1, 3]
  }]
```

but allQuestions is null. I don't seem to be able to get into the success function at all because when I step thru it with breakpoint it goes right over the success option and returns. I tried even just doing an alert(result) with no success (no pun intended).

Any insight will be most appreciated.

Comment: Try wrapping the keys in double quotes like "question", "choices", etc into your test.json.

Answer (score 0):

The piece that you're probably missing is that AJAX calls are **asynchronous**.

So what happens is:

```
- you initialize allQuestions
- you *start* requesting allQuestions to the server
- you render the page, and allQuestions is still NULL
- the server replies, but now it's too late.
```

So what do you do? You place the rendering functions within the AJAX success function:

```
$.post(..., function(reply) {
    allQuestions = reply;
    renderOnPage(allQuestions);
});
```

You will probably discover that this approach no longer requires allQuestions to be a global - all relevant functions will just pass it along among themselves.

Comment: To verify it would be interesting where OP put the `alert(result)`

Comment: you mean I have to I have to place the all my functions like check-answer,button_render and the on() functions in success?

Comment: I put alert as only line in the success option.

Comment: I'm confused. Why use $.post. I want to get the json file off the server only and then store response in variable. I dont get your example. Is it shorthand for what I asked about putting all functions in success. So success is like a wrapper for just about whole script?

Comment: I see you're using $.post as shorthand ajax function. but what is renderOnPage(allQuestions) supposed to being doing?

Comment: If you look at this pastebin: http://pastebin.com/LfxXZ72n you'll see I still skip over the success option when i step thru script.

Comment: I'm curious. I was testing this using Aptana Studio's built in internal server via FIrefox. Could it be I need to be running script w/success calling to a real server?